# Android - Can't send message from my service to all clients

Tags: android

I make my android service to comunicate with all my activity. All work well but today, i wanna try to send message from service to all connected client.
Code in IncomingHandler

```
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_1:
                Log.i("RpcChannelService", "MSG_1");
                //send msg to all clients
                Message msgGpsEnable= Message.obtain(null,
                        RpcChannelService.MSG_1);
                for (Messenger client : mClients) {
                    try {
                        client.send(msgGpsEnable);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        Log.i("RpcChannelService", "handleMessage:MSG_GPS_ENABLE exception");
                    }
                }
                break;
          }
    }
```

When i run/debug this code, after pass thought this code, program make a forever loop.
Can anyone tell me why?
Thanks alot.

Comment: mClients is Messenger array stored all connected client.

Comment: My bad. I should create new instance of Message inside for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I should create new instance of Message inside loop.

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_1:
            Log.i("RpcChannelService", "MSG_1");
            //send msg to all clients

            for (Messenger client : mClients) {
                try {
                    Message msgGpsEnable= Message.obtain(null,
                    RpcChannelService.MSG_1);
                    client.send(msgGpsEnable);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.i("RpcChannelService", "handleMessage:MSG_GPS_ENABLE exception");
                }
            }
            break;
      }
}
```